# Taylor series in haskell

Tags: math, haskell, recursion, taylor-series

How to write Taylor series recursion data like this one:

```
fib = 0 : scanl (+) 1 fib
```

For example, I want promt something like this:

```
fac n = product[1..n]
sin' x = x : x^3/fac(3) : x^5/fac(5) : ...
sum $ take 10 (sin' (pi/6))
```

And get sum of 10 first elements of sine Taylor series.

Comment: The Taylor series has a coefficient for each x^n.  Can you write a function from n to the corresponding coefficient of x^n ?

Comment: You are right, I forgot about sign of elements in series.
Function for coefficient is:
(-1)^(n-1)
So, function of sine for every element of series is:
(-1)^(n-1) * x^n / n!, where n = [1..infinity]

Comment: I have made this code:
http://pastebin.com/7MAxFqNy
But currently have the errors. How could I run this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not quite the Taylor series for sin!  But here's a clue ...

```
products = scanl (*) 1 [1..]
powers x = map (x^) [0..]
exp' x = zipWith (/) (powers x) products

*Main> sum (take 10 (exp' 1))
2.7182815255731922
```

Comment: The use of scan and zipWith is particularly pleasing here. This is beautifully idiomatic.

Comment: A more efficient implementation of `powers x` would be `iterate (x*) 1`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman even better, `products` is not needed: `exp' x = scanl (*) 1 $ map (x /) [1..]` (or eliminate `map` by passing a different function to scanl)

Answer (score 3):

A common approach is to use a list to represent just the coefficients of the power series and write another function to evaluate the power series at a particular value.

For example, the power series 1/(1-x)^2 = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + ... would be represented by the list `[1,2,3,...]`.

To evaluate it, we need a function:

```
eval :: [Float] -> Float -> Float
```

The base case is easy:

```
eval [] x = 0
```

The inductive case can be defined recursively:

```
eval (a:as) x = a + x*...   -- left as an exercise
```

Of course, this `eval` won't terminate on an infinite list, so you'll have make sure to only give it finite lists:

```
sin' = [ 1, 0, - 1 / fac 3, 0, 1 / fac 5, 0, ... ]
eval (take 10 sin') (pi/6)
```

Now you just have to generate the coefficients for `sin'`. Note that in this case `10` refers to the highest power of `x` you want to sum to, not the number of non-zero terms in the sum.

Comment: You can also define `Num a => [a]` as an instance of the `Num` typeclass in a way that represent polynomial addition and multiplication, so that you can add and multiply Taylor series like `sin'` and `cos'` (again with finite precision).